# Any ideas why useEffect isn't recognizing my dependency?

Tags: reactjs, express, local-storage

I have a navbar that has different links for logged in vs not logged in. I have a variable called loggedIn that is set inside of local storage. My useEffect hook should be listening to localstorage and once the variable is detected update the navbar links. I do see the nav links change, but only after a page refresh which is obviously not ideal nor how it should be working. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

```
import React, {useState, Fragment, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css';

const Navbar = () => {
 
const [loggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoggedIn(localStorage.getItem('loggedIn'));
  }, [localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')]);

   

  const authLinks = (
    <div className="navbar">
      <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
      <Link to="#!">Logout</Link>
    </div>
  );
  const guestLinks = (
    <div className="navbar">
      <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
      <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="navbar">
        <Link className="header" to="/">
          Stock Bites
        </Link>
        {!loggedIn ? guestLinks : authLinks}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

```
 const login = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await Axios.post('http://localhost:4000/login', user);
      console.log(res);

      localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true);
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
      history.push('/profile');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I think you expect your `useEffect` dependency to make a function call, while it should be used to listed to externally committed changes to state variables.

Comment: What is the best way to get the nav links to update after logged in if not useEffect?

Comment: Did you try using `loggedIn` as a dependency instead of `localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')`?

Comment: `loggedIn` should be passed to Navbar from the parent (e.g. `const Navbar = ({logedIn}) => {`). When parent knows the login is successful, it will rerender Navbar with `loggedIn=true`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that and it didn't make a difference. I still have to refresh page to see the nav links update

Comment: Well, post the entire code (including the parent) and we will figure it out. Or put it together in a Sandbox.

Comment: `useContext` is another option.

Comment: I'll look into the useContext option. I was trying it this way because I was watching a code along and the developer used this code. Somehow it seemed to work for him but clearly not for me

Answer (score 0):

useEffect expects variable/fucnction/expression as a dependency
But if you want to include localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') in dependency array extract value from it

```
const localLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')
```

Then pass it inside the useEffect dependency, But if you are expecting that your component will re-render when localstorage is updated that will be not a case.

In your case useeffect will run only on first render, as to Lister LocalStorage update you need to add listner over localStorage.